# Jenkins + Sonar + Maven with poms in extra directory structure

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I have a (big) maven project with many modules which looks like this at the top

```
src/
maven-build/
```

src contains the tree with all the Java sources. maven-build contains the tree with all the poms

I can build everything fine with Jenkins, but when I add a Sonar analysis triggered through maven, Sonar complains that

```
[...]/src/x/y/Z.java is not in basedir [...]/maven-build
```

I already tried copying the Java files to the maven-build directory, but this doesn't help...

Is there a way to change the basedir on Sonar? Or can I solve this in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

I copy my root-pom to the directory containing the source-directories. You could also try copying the pom from maven-build to the directory containing "src". In that way, "[...]/src/x/y/Z.java" would be within basedir.

```
pom.xml
src/
maven-build/
```